# Make a vertical scroll inside an asp repeater using css2.1

Tags: asp.net, scroll, repeater, css

in my aspx page I'm calling a repeater, the problem is that I want a fix-sized page but I want to keep the scroll inside of the repeater so how can I do that ?

My asp div wouldn't take the overflow-y option saying it doesn't exist in css2.1 and the overflow option is giving me both vertical and horizontal scroll!

```
<asp:Repeater ID="TheRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="TheRepeater_OnItemDataBound" EnableViewState="true" EnableTheming="true">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div style="overflow-y: scroll;  margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; min-height:15px; ">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div >
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Object")%> - 

                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AssignedTo")%> 
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
            </div>  
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use This:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical">
<asp:Repeater ID="TheRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="TheRepeater_OnItemDataBound" EnableViewState="true" EnableTheming="true">
        <HeaderTemplate>            
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Object")%> - 

                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AssignedTo")%> 
                   </div>                      
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>               
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

Hope This Help.